# Register Apple Service using a .pem certificate

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, pem, pushsharp

I would like to send a test PUSH message to an iOS device. I am provided with the device token and one `.pem` file as certificate. But I cannot seem to find a way to create a new `ApplePushChannelSettings` object using this `.pem` file. The examples on the web all use a `.p12` file that come with a password.

```
//Create our push services broker
var push = new PushBroker();

//Registering the Apple Service and sending an iOS Notification
var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes("ApnsSandboxCert.p12"));
push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "pwd"));
push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                           .ForDeviceToken("DEVICE TOKEN HERE")
                           .WithAlert("Hello World!")
                           .WithBadge(7)
                           .WithSound("sound.caf"));
```

Should I ask for a `.p12` certificate for the target app or is there a way to use a `.pem` file with *PushSharp*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, all Push notifications services ask for a `.p12` certificate. You should try that.

**EDIT:**
After a [quick search](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp), I think that you don't have a choice. `.p12` it is.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can, I've managed to do it after a long time of researching. First, get this: https://github.com/jrnker/CSharp-easy-RSA-PEM. It contains a class called **Crypto** and another called **Helpers** that I've used for sending push with .pem files.

```
    X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string pemFilePath, string pemFilePassword)
    {

        var pemString = File.ReadAllText(pemFilePath);
        var certificateString = readSectionFromPem(pemString, "CERTIFICATE");
        var keyString = readSectionFromPem(pemString, "RSA PRIVATE KEY");
        var certificateBuffer = Helpers.GetBytesFromPEM(certificateString, PEMtypes.PEM_X509);

        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBuffer);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = Crypto.DecodeRsaPrivateKey(keyString, pemFilePassword);
        certificate.PrivateKey = provider;

        return certificate;     
    }

    string readSectionFromPem(string pem, string section)
    {
        string header = String.Format("-----BEGIN {0}-----", section);
        string footer = String.Format("-----END {0}-----", section);
        int start = pem.IndexOf(header);
        int end = pem.IndexOf(footer, start) + footer.Length;
        return pem.Substring(start, end - start);
    }
```

After you obtain the **X509Certificate2** instance, you can instantiate your **ApnsConfiguration** and **ApnsBroker** instances with the following code

```
ApnsConfiguration config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, GetCertificate(certificatePath, certificatePass));
ApnsServiceBroker apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);
```